# Removing a column from a dataframe based on a conditional

Tags: r

I am having a lot of difficulty removing a column from a data frame in R when the the choice is dependent on a conditional. For instance, I would like to remove either the male or female columns depending on whether the gender is male or female. Person represents a dataframe. The followingis my code:

```
Gender <- "male"
dd <- subset(person, select = c(-Male))
de <- subset(person, select = c(-Female))
person1 <- ifelse( Gender=="male", dd, de)
```

This code results in the listing of the first column in the data frame. The head of the data frame is below. By the way variables dd and de work fine. Only the if else statement is a problem perhaps because My conditional is outside the dataframe. When I bring the Gender inside the data frame vector I get a NULL result .

Similarly if use the following code to remove the column, it works, but I am stuck on the if else component

```
Myvars <- names(person) %in% c("Female")
DL <- person [! Myvars]
```

The data frame

```
 RoundDownAge    Male    Female
 54  938202  969252
 54  938202  969252
 54  938202  969252
 54  938202  969252
 54  938202  969252
 54  938202  969252
```

Thank you

Comment: what is expected dataframe?

Comment: Agree with @Ananta best way to ask these questions is to show us what you have and to show us what you expect.

Comment: The expected dataframe will have two columns RoundDownAge and Male. However, if gender is female (see first line of code) the two columns would be RoundDownAge and Female.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this code work for you?

```
person1 <- subset(person,select=c(ifelse(Gender=='male',-Male,-Female)))
```

Comment: @user3063214: If you get answers which solves your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.